# Android home activity without application chooser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-homebutton

I have an Android activity that opens when the device is open and when Home Button is pushed the activity is show. I did this using having this intent associated to the activity:

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

First time I push home button I get the message

Complete action using:

- *My Program*
- Launcher

Does exists a form to avoid this dialog and make that the application that executes my intent will be *My program* automatically?

Note: I don't want have to select always *My program* and *Use always to do this action*

Comment: Thanks to the downvote. Great community!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does exists a form to avoid this dialog and make that the application that executes my intent will be My program automatically?

You are welcome to build your own Android firmware (a.k.a., "ROM mod") that has your program as the sole home screen implementation, then install that firmware on devices that you own (or can convince the device owners to install it).

Otherwise, no, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I feared this. Thanks for the help